# Scope object doesn't change without $scope in Angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-scope

I've set up a small fiddle here http://jsfiddle.net/SPMfT/137/ and I was wondering if someone could explain me why changing an object doesn't work, while changing properties of the object, or changing the object with "$scope" in front works.

The reason is that I try to avoid using scope in controller functions so they will be easier to test.

My real task is an 
    ng-click="reset(current, master)" 
with

```
$scope.reset = function (current, master) { angular.copy(current, master); }
```

This doesn't work, whereas this works:

```
$scope.reset = function (current, master) { angular.copy($scope.current, master); }
```

Both 
    $scope.current 
and 
    $scope.master 
exist

Cheers

Update:

My problem was I wasn't updating the object itself. To solve the problem use e.g.

```
angular.extend(data, { name: 'change', game:'change' });
```

or

```
angular.copy({ name: 'change', game:'change' }, data);//Pay attention to order
```

Comment: using angular.extend() was the ticket for me. thanks

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The reason is you are creating a new object (and therefore a different reference) and assigning it to a local variable that was *previously pointing* to the same object.

```
$scope.change = function (data) {
    data = { name: 'change', game:'change' };
}
```

The `data` variable passed holds a reference to the same object of your `$scope.data` but you are assigning a *local* variable pointing to a reference of an object A to a new object B, *locally*. At that point, `$scope.data` still holds a reference to the same object it has before. All you are doing is changing the reference to the local variable and discarding it at the end of the function.

In your specific case, it should work (using `current` or `$scope.current`). I believe you are inverting the parameter in `angular.copy` as it should be `(source, destination)`. See this [updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/SPMfT/138/) for a simple demo.

Comment: Good explanation.
You were of course right and I had the angular.copy mixed up.
I realize now that I can use 
angular.extend(data, { name: 'change', game:'change' });
on the fiddle example.